# How to get active users of a specific page by Google analytics API?

Tags: real-time, google-analytics-api

I use `rt:activeUsers` metric to get active users on website for realtime data.

I want to get active users in real time for a specific page (`path` or `url`), not the whole website. Is there a way to implement it? I went through [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analytics/v3/) but gain no success.

Comment: have you tried adding a filter for rt:pagePath?

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo please put your answer as an `answer` to accept it.

Comment: Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the Real-time API is very limited it does allow you to use filters.  Filters are a kind of where clause.

The real-time documentation is also very limited but you can look at the documentation for [filters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters) on the core reporting API it works the same

```
filters=ga:browser%3D~%5EFirefox
```

I think you should check out the dimension `rt:pagePath` its probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

For anybody else looking for this below is an example of how I accomplished this in javascript.

I started with the sample at: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/

That sample uses a extension to the embed api to get active users: active-users.js

I didn't know where to get that active-users.js file so I just used the developer tools in Chrome and grabbed it that way. Saved it locally and linked to it in my page. If anyone knows a official location to get that please comment below. Thx.

If you look at the source to that file, I modifed the pollActiveUsers function to add a filters parameter like so:

```
pollActiveUsers_: function () {
                var t = this.get(),
                i = 1e3 * (t.pollingInterval || 5);
                if (isNaN(i) || i < 5e3)
                    throw new Error("Frequency must be 5 seconds or more.");
                this.polling_ = !0,
                gapi.client.analytics.data.realtime.get({
                    ids: t.ids,
                    metrics: "rt:activeUsers",
                    filters: t.filters
                }).then(function (t) {
                    var e = t.result,
                    s = e.totalResults ? +e.rows[0][0] : 0,
                    n = this.activeUsers;
                    this.emit("success", {
                        activeUsers: this.activeUsers
                    }),
                    s != n && (this.activeUsers = s, this.onChange_(s - n)),
                    1 == this.polling_ && (this.timeout_ = setTimeout(this.pollActiveUsers_.bind(this), i))
                }
                    .bind(this))
            },
```

Now in my page javascript I can call it like so:

```
var activeUsers = new gapi.analytics.ext.ActiveUsers({
                container: 'active-users-container',
                pollingInterval: 5,
                filters: "rt:pagePath==/somepath/somepage/",
                ids: "ga:<yourviewid>"
            });
```

Hope that helps somebody.